# Facebook page redirecting based on current location

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect

I want to visit the following facebook page-
https://www.facebook.com/VisaSingapore
But when I enter this url in browser it always redirecting to.
https://www.facebook.com/VisaIND?brand_redir=225803677544474
I am accessing it from India and I understand that facebook redirecting the page based on my current location.
I changed my Current City to Singapore from facebook Profile->CurrentCity but still it is redirecting.
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be programming-related, but rather a FB user support issue.

Answer (score 31):

I got the answer. Just add `?brand_redir=DISABLE` after the url, now the url will be:

https://www.facebook.com/VisaSingapore?brand_redir=DISABLE

Comment: How to do it on mbasic.facebook.com?

Answer (score 2):

You probably wont be able to access that page unless you are in a zone that the page is made available in. i.e. Singapore in this case. The page admin decides where certain content is served and that may be due to many reasons. If you could access it from a zone outside of the zone specified by the page admin then that does not seem correct.